# Visual Studio 2013 XAML intellisense error

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I have VS2013 Pro installed and for some reason it doesn't autocompletes font families in `WPF` `XAML`.
for example if I have the following statement:

```
<TextBlock Text="Loading Data" FontFamily=""/>
```

Pressing `Ctrl` + `Space` (or anything else) inside the FontFamily quotes does nothing.
Running on `Windows 7`.

**PS**

Testing on the same machine with VS 2010 Pro gives the same result.

Comment: If you open it in Blend, do you see the fonts?

Comment: Sounds like it's the time to re-install your PC :D